# Java charAt() Method Crashes in For Loop

Tags: java, file, input

The following code should read 5 strings from a .dat file and then print each individual character from each of the strings.

```
File file = new File("tictactoe.dat");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
String str = "";
int x;
for ( x = 0; x < numGames; x++) {
    str = scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        out.println(str.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

But the program throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  There's nothing wrong with the `Scanner`, as tests have shown that it picks up each line in my file fine. But when attempting to get and then print a certain character in each string, the program crashes.

Strangely, outside of the loop `charAt()` works without error.

Why does calling the method within the loop cause the progam to crash?

**UPDATE:** I made some ridiculous mistake copying the code I was using.  Please see updated code above. Also, the program "crashes" due to a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which I am not catching.

Comment: Does each line have at least numGames characters in it?

Comment: Yes it does. No problem with the length of the string.

Comment: When you say "crash", do you mean a fatal exception (something with a stack trace we could look at) or JVM dump-type crash?

Comment: Why are you only printing one character from each line?  This should print the first character of the first line, the second character of the second line, etc.  It seems unlikely that you want to do that.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: can you post the 5 lines in the file and the value of `numGames` also.

Comment: Made a stupid error copying in code. Please see updated question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop isn't doing what you want it to do. You say:

> ... and then print each individual character from each of the strings.

But what it's actually doing is getting line 1, and printing only the first character from that line, then getting the second line and printing the second character, third line and third character, and so on. If you're printing each character on a separate line, you need to have a second loop inside your first one that iterates through the characters in the string in order to print all their individual characters.

```
char[] characters = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(characters[i]);
}
```

Or even better, if you use a for-each loop:

```
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Or just `System.out.println(str)` and avoid all the picking apart of the string and putting it back together.

Comment: Notice my use of `println` instead of `print`. I said, "If you're printing each character on a separate line, ..." But yes, of course if you're just printing the characters all on one line, then `println(str)` is better.

Comment: @TheKraken Your update as written should work just fine. Is it still giving you problems?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm trying the exact same code I used before on a different machine and it works fine. Hence, I'm unsure as to what the real problem was. However, the code is working now without any logic errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected the error to be `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` as you are printing the first letter from the first line and the second letter from the second line, etc. As you don't check whether such a letter exists, there comes a point where the line is not that long.

If that is not the cause I would

- read the exception post it in the question.
- step through your code with your debugger to find the bug in your code.

Answer (score 1):

you have confused number of lines, with number of characters in each line

```
File file = new File("tictactoe.dat");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
String str = "";
int x;
int y;
for ( x = 0; x < numGames; x++) {
    str = scan.nextLine();
    for (y = 0; y<str.length(); y++)
    {
        out.println(str.charAt(y));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. That was in fact the initial code I had. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

There's something strange in your logic. Assuming the DAT is:

```
12345
67890
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

Your code will print:

```
1
7
c
i
o
```

After all, you invoke "scanLine" numGames times and grab the X position on each new line.